# Scrollbar in datagrid dojo

Tags: datagrid, dojo

How to remove the horizontal scroll bar of Dojo Datagrid?  Even i remove scroll space for the scroll bar appears. How to eliminate?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your problem? The horizontal scrollbar should appear when the content is wider than the container node. You can avoid this by using CSS `overflow:hidden`, but it's not recommended. You should try to reduce the width of your content.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the CSS for the dojoxGridScrollbox to have overflow-x:none, but its not recommended.

Alternatively, you could have one of the column widths be "auto" instead of fixed pixel.  Assuming your grid is wider than the data you intend to display, this will typically remove the scrollbars.